# Eloquent Mysql time type precision

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, artisan-migrate

I use Laravel 5.6.x framework, i have a connection on a Mysql database of which one of the tables contains a Time(6) field type.

sample value : `'00:01:02.154120'`

I want my model to receive the value with same precision but i always get a truncated value corresponding to `'H:i:s'` format even i cast my column to datetime or string.

I created my table from migration and i saw Blueprint support well precision option for time type since version 5.5. So i guess there is a way to retrieve the whole value ?

How can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24214

It's caused by a bug in PHP that will be fixed in 7.3: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/3257